# apache/python/mod_wsgi - See what python code a mod_wsgi child process is running?

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, django, mod-wsgi

I'm using Debian, Apache and mod_wsgi to run a Django application. One of the apache child processes is using lots of CPU. I need to find out what's causing it. Is there anyway to see, given a apache child PID, what python code is being run? Sorta like strace for python/mod_wsgi? However I'm trying to debug a live system, so I can't make any changes to the apache/mod_wsgi/django set up.

Answer (score 1):

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Extracting_Python_Stack_Traces